# How to contain unassociated entities in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Sample query:

```
TableRegistry::getTableLocator()
    ->get('Parents')
    ->find()
    ->contain([
        'Children' => function (Query $query) {
            return $query->where([
                'Children.code = Parent.code'
            ]);
        }
    ])
```

`Parent` and `Children` tables only have `code` as common field.

How do I define their association?

How do I contain unassociated entities?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56472466/how-to-contain-unassociated-entities-in-cakephp/59101044#59101044

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the `foreignKey` and `bindingKey` in association configuration

In ParentsTable.php:

```
$this->hasMany('Children', [
    'bindingKey' => 'code',
    'foreignKey' => 'code'
]);
```

This config will set which fields to look for when associating entities.

Then you could associate entities on your controller like this:

```
// This query will contain children where Children.code === Parent.code
TableRegistry::getTableLocator()
    ->get('Parents')
    ->find()
    ->contain('Children');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the relationship between those tables througth ParentesTable as @kgbph explained.

Although in your exemple I think the better solution is use Cake's TreeBehavior. Here's the [link](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html) to the documentation.